# I heard someone use the term "dogs body" what does it mean?

Tags: etymology

I heard someone use the British slang "dogs body".  What does it mean?

Comment: When in doubt...google!

Comment: The body of a dog? Dog's body... NOT! One word, if you don't mind :)

Comment: Originally I asked for derivation of "dogs body" as one word without quotes, then asked for it with quotation marks.  I asked for etymology.  I asked for "the meaning" of… Finally I included the expression "British slang" hoping that your site would recognize it as a

Answer (score 2):

In the 19th century “dog’s body” was sailor slang for a common shipboard meal composed primarily of boiled peas, with powdered ships-biscuit or flour added as a thickener.

I suspect that *body* here represents a euphemism for something even less savory.

Around WW I the term came to be applied to junior officers:

[image]
 —Montague Thomas Hainsselin, *The Curtain of Steel*, 1991.

As these were typically charged with whatever unpleasant duties their seniors did not care to perform, the term passed into civilian use—often in the collocation *general dogsbody*—to signify any drudge responsible for menial tasks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/ lists dogsbody as :

noun (plural dogsbodies)

British informal

a person who is given menial tasks to do, especially a junior in an office:

*I got myself a job as typist and general dogsbody on a small magazine.*

Comment: That's ODO, not OED (easy mistake to make). A similar definition occurs at **2b** in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56503?rskey=7Wpw3o&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (may require login)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I need to edit my second answer to another question too.Much appreciated.